# Which type of key .NET assemblies uses for signing and how to create it?

Tags: .net, assemblies, signing

I have read many [MSDN articles about assembly signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123.aspx) and I haven't found nothing about creating the key, just about creating the file, but the 3 methods listed to create a file needs a pre-generated key. Can you provide me a link to a tutorial to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f05ezxy.aspx) how you create a new Public/Private key pair. You can do the same thing from within the VS UI - see Signing tab in Project Properties.

Answer (score 1):

As Anton suggests, you can generate one easily using sn.exe. The problem with this is that it's no good for verifiying your identity as a publisher because there is no trust chain established for self-generated keys. If you want to sign your assemblies so that your identity can be verified then you'll need to get a certificate from a trusted supplier, such as [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sn.exe provide by microsoft to generate à Key pair.

After that you ll have to do:

```
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFileAttribute(@"..\..\key.snk")]
```

Hope this could help :)

Comment: Note that the use of this attribute for keypair creation was made obsolete in VS 2005.